# Let $G$ be a finite group with $|G| = 70$, suppose $a \in G$ satisfies $a^{21} = e$. Prove that $a^7 = e$. Which of the following proofs is wrong?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> Let $G$ be a finite group with $|G| = 70$, suppose $a \in G$ satisfies $a^{21} = e$. Prove that $a^7 = e$. Which of the following proofs is wrong?

[image]

I got really confused here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: the identity element and the last proof : do you see a problem?

Comment: The proof A is a pure calculation. You may have noticed the similarity between the proof B and the proof C. They are almost identical except for the implication of the fact that "$|a|$ is a divisor of 70 and $|a|$ is also a divisor of 21". This fact doesn't imply that $|a|$ is the greatest common divisor. It only tells us that $|a|$ is a common divisor. One counter example is given by @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг: $a=e$ and $|a|=1$.

Comment: In Proofs A and C, some of the signs that are supposed to be equal signs actually look like minus signs. If possible, please upload a new image that makes the equal signs correctly appear as such.

Comment: Hint $\ {\rm ord}(a) =: n\mid 70,21\iff n\mid \gcd(70,21)=7.\ $ From $\,n\mid 7\,$ we can't deduce $\,n=7\,$ without further hypotheses, since possibly $\,n = 1\ \ $

Answer (score 1):

Proof C is invalid. You can only conclude that the order of $a$ divides $\gcd(70, 21) = 7.$ So we could have $a=e,$ which has order $1 \ne 7.$